# macOS Monterey Boot Camp Assistant disk cannot be partitioned

Tags: macos, bootcamp, partition, fusion-drive

I have a late 2015 iMac 27" - which previously had a 32Gb Fusion Drive and 1TB HDD... sometime ago I swapped out the 32Gb for a 1TB NVMe drive and the 1TB HDD for a 1TB SSD as i was dual booting macos on the NVMe drive and Fedora on the SSD.  I've now opted to dual boot macos and Windows - and couldn't achieve this in the setup above.  I read a post stating I had to reset the Fusion drive - which I've now done and done a clean install of macos Monterey.

However, despite the Fusion Drive appearing to show the correct combined volume of 2TB - I constantly receive a message saying there isn't enough space to be successfully partitioned - I also can't manually partition this through Disk Utility either in macos or macos recovery.  I don't have Time Machine enabled and there are no snapshots.

[image: BOOTCAMP MESSAGE]

[image: TERMINAL OUTPUT]

[image: DISK UTILITY OUTPUT]

[image: PARTITION MAP]

Comment: Add the output from the command `diskutil list` to your question.

Comment: ok - so I decided to just go with the nuclear option as i had backups of everything i needed anyway.. I booted from a Monterey USB installer disk and removed the fusion drive by deleting the container through diskutil.  I then formatted both drives completely.  I reinstalled macOS Monterey on the 1TB NVME drive and booted into it.  I then ran boot camp assistant which decided to play ball this time (despite it not working initially hence why i had to faff around with resetting the fusion drive!)

Comment: - so I then split the disk 50% macos and 50% windows and installed Windows 11.  Pretty straightforward install - with the only hiccups being having to use regedit to modify a couple of files to bypass TPM 2.0 checking and then having to manually install the drivers for my sound and WiFi.  *BUT* it's all up and running now.  I now have macOS Monterey and Windows 11 on the NVMe drive with the 1TB SSD as a media storage volume.

Comment: Could you post an answer where you basically repeat what is in your comments? You can then delete your comments. Also, could you return later and accept your own answer. This will let others know an acceptable answer was found to your question.